# Invoking WebMethods with XmlHttpRequest and Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest, webmethod

I have what should be a relatively simple task that's frankly got me stumped. I've researched it until my brain is fried, and now I'm punting, and asking you guys for help.

Here's the scenario:

- I have an ASPX page (Q2.aspx) that is decorated with the `WebService`,
  `WebServiceBinding`, and `ScriptService` attributes.
- That page contains a method, `GetAllContacts`, that is decorated with the `WebMethod`
  attribute and returns a string containing JSON data. (For what it's worth, the page
  itself contains no other controls or functionality.)
- I have an HTML page that contains JavaScript which uses the `XmlHttpRequest`
  object to invoke the `GetAllContacts` WebMethod on the ASPX page and transform
  the JSON data into an HTML table.
- I have verified that my `Web.Config` file contains the appropriate protocol handlers
  for `HttpGet` and `HttpPut` in the `WebServices` section under `System.Web.webServices`.
- I have verified that my `Web.Config` file contains the `ScriptModule` entry under the
  `System.webServer.modules` section, and that it matches the appropriate documentation.

However, when I view the HTML page in a browser, the following occur:

- The web request goes through, but the results are for the unprocessed HTML from the ASPX page.
- The `GetAllContacts` method is never invoked, as evidenced by setting a breakpoint in its code.
- The code to invoke the Web service, however, is invoked, and the JavaScript callback
  function that is invoked upon request completion is properly invoked.

It appears that the JavaScript code is largely set up correctly, but for some reason that is completely escaping me at this point, the HTML page will simply not execute the `WebMethod` on the ASPX page, and simply returns the page as though it were a plain HTML `GET` request. Clearly, an HTML document can't be evaluated by JavaScript's `eval` function, which brings me to my problem. (Also note that the JSON data appears nowhere in the HTML that's returned.)

I am, frankly, baffled. I've looked at dozens of Microsoft articles, StackOverflow posts, CodeProject articles, and who knows what else. My code *looks* like it's okay. But I know better. I'm missing something simple, stupid, and obvious. I just need someone to point it out to me.

Below you'll find the ASPX page code and the HTML code, in the hope that they'll shed some light.

**ASPX Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Q2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Satuit.Q2" enablesessionstate="False" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <form runat="server" id="frmMain"/>
    </body>
</html>
-- Codebehind
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace Satuit
{
    [WebService(Namespace="http://tempuri.org")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
    [ScriptService]
    public partial class Q2 : Page
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetAllContacts()
        {
            return LoadJsonData();
        }

        private static string LoadJsonData()
        {
            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {

                string xmlUri = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\XmlData\\Contacts.xml");
                string xslUri = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\XmlData\\Q2.xsl");

                using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlUri))
                {
                    var xpathDocument = new XPathDocument(xmlTextReader);
                    var xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

                    xslTransform.Load(xslUri);
                    xslTransform.Transform(xpathDocument, null, stringWriter);

                    return stringWriter.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
    var objectData; // Receives the objectified results of the JSON request.

    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Q2.aspx/GetAllContacts", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var jsonResultBuffer = xmlhttp.responseText;
                objectData = eval(jsonResultBuffer);
                DisplayTable();
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    function DisplayTable()
    {       
        var sHtml = "";     
        sHtml = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>First</th><th>Last</th><th>Address</th></tr>";           
        for(i = 0; i < objectData.length; i++)
        {
            sHtml += "<tr>";
            sHtml += "<td>" + objectData.ID;
            sHtml += "<td>" + objectData.firstName + "</td>";
            sHtml += "<td>" + objectData.lastName + "</td>";
            sHtml += "<td>" + objectData.address + "</td>"; 
            sHtml += "</tr>"
        }
        sHtml += "</table>"         
        document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML = sHtml;
    }    
</script>
```

**Dev Environment Details**

- Vista Ultimate SP 2
- Visual Studio 2008
- .NET Framework 3.5
- Solution has not yet been deployed, so it's running in the "local Web server"
  provided by Visual Studio. (Makes me wonder if I shouldn't just deploy IIS
  under Vista.)
- Note that the ASPX page containing the WebMethod and the HTML page reside within 
  the same solution.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think asp.net web service has to be called by using SOAP.

Comment: No, Fopfong, it doesn't.

Comment: Mike, where are you hosting your web service?  Is it installed in a virtual directory or as an application on the server?  If the page isn't processing, ASP.Net's processing is not being executed.  Make sure your IIS is set up correctly.  I'd guess it's the folder where your code lives.

Comment: @Cen, This solution hasn't yet been deployed, and it exists solely on my development machine. I added the environmnet information to the main post above. The WebService itself is in the same solution with the HTML page. And thanks for looking at this. I'm pulling my hair out!

Comment: Have you tried to see if you can use jQuery to perform this for you?  (Just as a test -- not as a solution)  An easier implementation may be using the AutocompleteExtender from the Ajax ToolKit.  Just trying to establish if we can communicate via ANY means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try the following using jquery to see the web service is accessible or not.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Q2.aspx/GetAllContacts",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
           alert("success");
        },
        error: function(response, aa) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
```

Thurein

Answer (score 4):

I think we need to call web method with POST request
try changing this part of code

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/Q2.aspx/GetAllContacts", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
            var jsonResultBuffer = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            objectData = jsonResultBuffer.d;
            DisplayTable();
    }
};
```

Response is returned in JSON format with "d" as the key in xmlhttp.responseText

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to set the header for the response in XMLHttpRequest.